# Context in mocha test is undefined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

So I'm using mocha and node to test some apis.  I have a test that goes

```
import { describe, before, it, xit } from 'mocha';

describe('test my scenarios dude', () => {
   before('do all my pre-test stuff', () => {
     const blah = blah;
   });

   it('tests my really useful test', () => {
     const testName = this.test.ctx.currentTest.fullTitle();
   });
});
```

The 'this' is undefined though.  How can I get the test name?

Answer (score 5):

https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

as docs says `Passing arrow functions (“lambdas”) to Mocha is discouraged`
use `function` instead

```
describe('test my scenarios dude', function() {
   before('do all my pre-test stuff', function() {
     const blah = blah;
   });

   it('tests my really useful test', function() {
     const testName = this.test.ctx.currentTest.fullTitle();
   });
});
```

also you can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). they don't have `this`